# Adding Data to a GridView

Tags: gridview

I'm trying to display some data from a Stored Procedure into my `GridView`. What I'm doing is onLoad; creating a DataTable, adding two rows to it (debugged and there's definitely data in them) and then;

GridView1.DataSource = DataTable

However my GridView comes back empty every time. Why is this?

Comment: and more tags, to your question like asp.net, or android so that your question can be view by many other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

to load the data

Comment: Oh thought you only needed a DataBind if you wanted the GridView permanently linked to the datatable. That worked in so far as the GridView has two rows now, but no columns and hence no data.

Answer (score 0):

**On The page load we can bind the data with data table**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    con.Open();
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();

    string CommandText1 = "select * from TRAVEL_Preferences_INFO where USER_ID='" + str_USER_ID + "'";
    DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText1, con);
    DS.Reset();
    DB.Fill(DS);
    DT = DS.Tables[0];
    grdTravelPreference.DataSource = DT;
    grdTravelPreference.DataBind();
}
```